# How do you fill dropdown from a database using R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to fill a drowndown list in an R shiny application with the results of a query from a database.

```
#I have a global.r file where i put this code:
getData<- function()
{
  ....this function returns a single column of names. I tested that it does work.
}

#Now in my ui.r file I try to use the function to populate a dropdown list like:
source('global.r')
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
selectInput("names", "Select Data",getData(),selected="Name 1" multiple = FALSE)
),
```

When I run this the dropdown is populated with the header of the query but not the entire list that is returned in the query.

Any ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually I don't where you problem could come from, it should works if getData returns a vector. But don't `source('global.r')` in your Ui, if getData is supposed to be reactive it won't work because ui.r runs only once (at app load). If global.r, ui.r and server.r are in the same directory, global.r will be automatically sourced when you run the app.

Comment: ok I took the source('global.r') out of the ui.r page. Now I get the error: Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: What's the str of the object returned by `getData` ?

Comment: getData() returns a list of names like: Bob, Joe, Harry, etc...It is one column of data. it looks like: rbind("Joe","BOb","Harry")

Comment: You probably just want a simple vector of data. Try selecting that column (even if there's only 1) via something like `getData()[,1]`

Comment: @user3022875 - Does it return an actual list or a vector.  You need to be careful with your terminology.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the drop down to be reactive use uiOutput("names") instead of selectInput in ui.R. Then in your server.R you want a function like:

```
output$names<-renderUI({
  selectInput("names", "Select Data", choices=getData(), selected=names[1])
})
```

http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html
http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/htmlOutput.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the columns being retrieved via the query have names.

If you're using `dbGetQuery` to get your results from the database, the results are returned in the form of a dataframe, even if it is only one column.

```
res <- dbGetQuery(conn, 'select column_name from table_name')
is.data.frame(res) # this will be true
```

The name of the dataframe column is used as a header in the selectInput choices dropdown.
If you do not name the columns in your sql query, then the query header shows up in the selectInput choices dropdown. For example if you perform an operation like max(column_name) vs picking up a direct column.

So instead of this

```
get_data <- function(){
  conn <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, Connection_string)
  on.exit(RJDBC::dbDisconnect(conn))
  q <- "SELECT distinct split_part(column_name, '.', 1) from table_name;"
  return (dbGetQuery(conn, q))
}
```

try

```
get_data <- function(){
  conn <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, Connection_string)
  on.exit(RJDBC::dbDisconnect(conn))
  q <- "SELECT distinct split_part(column_name, '.', 1) my_name from table_name;"
  return (dbGetQuery(conn, q))
}
```

and notice the difference in the dropdown choices.
Any feedback is appreciated.