# how to fill dropdown from database with r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, rodbc, sqlyog

I have created the dropdown in shiny package . I am not able to populate it with the column in my database tables.

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

h2("DATA ANIMATION"),




 sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

 uiOutput("names")
 selectInput("School",label="School",choices=c('ABSC','ASDJ','KJRH')),
 selectInput("Standard",label="Standard",choices=c('1','2','3','4')),
 selectInput("Section",label="Section",choices=c('A','B','C')),
 selectInput("Subject",label="SUBJECT",choices=c('ENG','MATH','SCI')),
             sliderInput("slide", "select exam:", 
                         min = 1, max = 4, value = 1,animate=T)

),
  mainPanel(
     h4("GRAPH")

  )
 ))
)
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
db <- odbcConnect("Classic")


shinyserver(
function(input,output){
output$names<-renderUI({
  selectInput("names", "Select Data", choices=getData(), selected=names[1])
})


}
)
```

**global.r**

```
getData<- function()
{ 

 }
```

i have also connected the database in R using RODBC.
i have the query in SQLYOG .

```
"SELECT DISTINCT a.name FROM schools a, years b, contracts c
WHERE a.current_year_id = b.id AND b.name = '2014-2015'
AND a.id = c.school_id "
```

which displays only one column .
i want this column to be populated inside my dropdown .

Comment: The answer to this question might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463079/how-do-you-fill-dropdown-from-a-database-using-r-shiny